# linking font files in the css does not work in firefox (but works in every other browser)

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I have the following code:

```
#entrance {
    margin: 20% auto auto auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Baron Neue';
    src: url('fonts/baron.otf');
}
```

This allows the text to be rendered in the desired font in chrome, ie, safari, and opera, but not firefox.  All I get is times new roman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the @font-face property.

```
@font-face {  
   font-family: Baron Neue;   
   src: local('Baron Neue'),   
   url('fonts/baron.otf');  
   font-weight: 400; 
}
```

see http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/

Comment: Can you tell me why I need that `local("Baron Neue")` twice?

Comment: You can use different font formats there if needed.. I removed it.

Comment: Different browsers require different font formats. To get your site to render correctly on all of them, you must include several (4) font formats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%40font-face